# Trying to write a function to clear all input and checkbox elements in passed-in form name

Tags: javascript, forms

A form name:

```
    <form name="PopulateModemALL" ID="PopulateModemALL"  action="populate_modemALL" >
```

A button in my form:

```
    <input ID="ModemAllTableClear" class="ButtonTables_Clear" type="button"  value="Clear"  name="clear_ModemALLTable" onclick="ClearFormElements('PopulateModemALL')"/>
```

My non-working javascript:

```
    function ClearFormElements(formId) 
      {
         // var this_form = document.getElementById(formId);
         var inputs = document.forms["formId"].getElementsByTagName("input") ;
         for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
           {
             document.formId.elements[i].value="" ;
           }

         var inputs = document.forms["formId"].getElementsByTagName("checkbox");
         for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
           {
             document.formId.elements[i].checked=false ;
           }
       }
```

Besides my indenting, what's causing this to not work?

I've spent way too many hours on this, starting from scratch.

Thanks!

======================================

Okay, this is my latest and it too doesn't work.
Any clues/suggestions out there?

```
    function ClearFormElements(formId) 
    {
      var nElements = document.formId.elements.length ;
      for (var i = 0; i < nElements; i++)
      {
        if (document.formId.elements[i].type === "input")
          { document.formId.elements[i].value="" ;  }

        if (document.formId.elements[i].type === "checkbox")
          { document.formId.elements[i].checkbox=false ;  }

        if (document.formId.elements[i].type === "textarea")
          { document.formId.elements[i].textarea="" ;  }  
      }
    }
```

Thanks everybody!

Comment: I would recommend using reset function for this.  Example - document.getElementById("myForm").reset();

Comment: You declared `inputs` a second time. Consider removing the `var` for your second `inputs`. Also, could you consider changing `forms["formId"]` to `forms[formId]`? Because the former is finding a form with id as `formId`.

Comment: Akshey, I am separately using the reset type to revert the form to as-initially-loaded.  This is to clear the form in preparation for individual field entry to perform a search.  I vascillated between the reset and trying this.  I like that reset, it solves a potentially big problem.  Thank you.

Comment: Jia, both good suggestions, (keepers), but alas it still does not work for me.
  I certainly could do what I know works, which is to clear every field individually, but that's not what I want to do.  e.g.:  PopulateModemALL.wireless_no.value="" ;
Thank you too.

Comment: Okay, I modified it, and still it's a NOGO.

Comment: _In what way_ does it not work?  Is it clearing some but not all fields? Is nothing at all happening?  Is there an error in the javascript console?  Have you stepped through it in the javascript debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your *latest* that doesn't work, there are a few problems.

`document.formId` is not a good way to get the form; your lines like this ...

```
var nElements = document.formId.elements.length;
if (document.formId.elements[i].type === "input")
```

... are getting `undefined` for `document.formId` and resulting in the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined` in my debugger (Chrome)

Instead, refer to `document[formId]` — `document[formId].elements.length;` produces `3` in the debugger.

Other problems ...

- `elements[i].type === "input"` doesn't match anything. Here you want `elements[i].type === "text"`
- `elements[i].textarea=""` changes the textarea *object* to the empty string. You want to clear the *value*, like `elements[i].value = ""`

The resulting function is this:

```
function ClearFormElements(formId)
{
    var nElements = document[formId].elements.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < nElements; i++)
    {
        if (document[formId].elements[i].type === "text") {
            document[formId].elements[i].value = "";
        }

        if (document[formId].elements[i].type === "checkbox") {
            document[formId].elements[i].checked = false;
        }

        if (document[formId].elements[i].type === "textarea") {
            document[formId].elements[i].value = "";
        }
    }
}
```

and you can see it in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/0dp4ov66/)

Beware, there are [other types](http://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes) besides `"text"` now with HTML5 elements there are input type= `tel`, `email`, `number` etc. which `.type === "text"` won't catch.

Comment: Stephen, you have made my day and then some!
Many many thanks!
I've put this into a good place for reference.